# How many characters need to be added to a string to make a palindrome

Tags: algorithm

I just faced an interview in TCS , My last question was to write an algorithm to find how many characters need to be added in a string to make it a palindrome. I started out, but wasnt able to complete. what would be a way to find that?

Comment: Google is the way dude..

Comment: Find the leftmost character in the right half of the string that is a potential "mirror point" of a palindrome. It induces the solution. Also consider even-length palindromes

Comment: Why dont you show what you tried? Does it really help you to have other people answer your interview questions for you?

Comment: Is `I` (or another single letter) a palindrome? Is `aa` a palindrome? All these are in the dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

```
String palindrome = "helllllll";

char [] chars = palindrome.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    int j = 0;
    for (; j < chars.length - i; j++) {
        if (chars[i+j] != chars [chars.length - 1-j])
            break;
    }
    if (j == chars.length - i) {
        System.out.println (i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As what `Niklas` said:

`Find the leftmost character in the right half of the string that is a potential "mirror point" of a palindrome. It induces the solution. Also consider even-length palindromes`

So as an example code that explains your question, this performs a palindrome test and then print it out in reverse without characters like '!', ', or '?'

And i have marked out the process that answers your question with a caption:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Variables and arrays
    int const index = 30;
    char Phrase[index];
    char Reverse[index];
    char* Palindrome = Reverse;
    int i, j;

    cout << "Please enter a sentence to be tested as a palindrome: ";
    cin.getline(Phrase, 30);
    int length = strlen(Phrase);

    bool test = true;

    for(i = 0, j = length-1; i < j; i++, j--) //Loops from zero to half of the string
    {
        if(test) // if it is a palindrome so far
        {
            while(!isalpha(Phrase[i]) && i < j) { i++; }
            while(!isalpha(Phrase[j]) && i < j) { j--; }

            if(Phrase[i] != Phrase[j]) //Check if the characters match
            {
                test = false;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if(test)
    {
        cout << endl << "Phrase/Word is a Palindrome." << endl << endl;
        for(j = strlen(Phrase) - 1; j >= 0; Palindrome++, j--)
        {
            *Palindrome = Phrase[j];
        }
        cout << "The phrase and reverse statement is: " << Reverse << endl << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl << "Phrase/Word is not a Palindrome." << endl << endl;
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this probably works for testing whether an input string is a palindrome, it does not answer the OP's question. Why don't you change it so that it does?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError better?

Comment: I was hoping for something along the lines of "The following string is the minimum that needs to be added to turn the input phrase into a palindrome:"....